# Shim config not supported in Node, may or may not work

Tags: node.js, requirejs, r.js

I am working on a project which works fine on browser , now we are trying to run it on server side using nodejs.

I have below configurations :

- node : v4.2.1
- npm : v2.14.7

and when I am trying to run my project on nodejs , getting the error as :

```
Shim config not supported in Node, may or may not work
```

Since the modules and dependencies (AMD) are working fine on browser I assume the shims config are correct .

Please let me know if I am missing something ?

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1443

Regards
Manish

Answer (score 0):

> Since the modules and dependencies (AMD) are working fine on browser I assume the shims config are correct .

That's an incorrect assumption. The problem is that Node.js operates with a set of basic assumptions that are very different from how browsers work. Consider this statement:

```
var foo = "something";
```

If you execute this at the top of your scope in Node.js, you've created a variable which is local to the file Node is executing. If you *really* want to make it global, then you have to explicitly shove it into `global`.

Now, put the same statement at the top of the scope of a script you load in a browser with the `script` element. The same statement *creates a global variable.* (The variable is global whether or not `var` is present.)

RequireJS' `shim` configuration is used for scripts that expect the second behavior. They expect a) that anything they declare at the top of their scope is leaked to the global space and b) that anything that has been leaked to the global space by scripts they depend on is available in the global space. Both expectations are almost always false in Node. (It would not be impossible for a module designed for node to manipulate `global` but that's very rare.)

The author of RequireJS explained in this [issue report](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/703) that he does not see it advisable for RequireJS to try to replicate the browser behavior in Node. I agree with him. If you want to run front-end code in the back-end you should replace those modules that need `shim` in the browser with modules that are designed to run in Node.